# c++20 ranges view to vector

Tags: c++, c++20

Now that the C++20 ranges implementation is actually here and released under GCC 10.2, I would like to know how to convert a ranges view back to an actual container, like a vector.
I've found this question ( [Range view to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808030/range-view-to-stdvector) ) that asked the same thing for the pre-release version but I would like to know if since its been released, have there been any new methods made to convert from a view to a container? Or is that single answer on that question still the best solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range view to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808030/range-view-to-stdvector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this says C++20, but going forward the answer is C++23's [std::ranges::to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to). It is a function template that has various ways to use it, including pipe or function (`std::ranges::to<std::vector>(intsView)` or `intsView | std::ranges::to<std::vector>()`), and implicit or explicit value-type (`std::ranges::to<std::set>(intsView)` or `std::ranges::to<std::set<int>>(intView)`). It also supports allocators. We have an implementation of roughly this in our codebase and use it all the time. There are so many cases that you want to collect a bunch of values together into a container, and `std::ranges::to` provides a great, concise, expressive API for doing exactly that. It even supports maps:

```cpp
// Project out the "foo" field of this->m_database
auto map = std::ranges::to<absl::flat_hash_map>(
    this->m_database | std::views::transform([&](const auto& row) {
        return std::pair{row.first, row.second.foo}; 
    })
);
```

Comment: Marking this as the new answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use it as after the pipe symbol, i.e. `| std::views::transform(...) | std::ranges::to<...>()`

Answer (score 17):

Easiest thing to do would be to use range-v3, which has a conversion operator exactly for this. From [the examples](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
using namespace ranges;
auto vi =
    views::for_each(views::ints(1, 10), [](int i) {
        return yield_from(views::repeat_n(i, i));
    })
  | to<std::vector>();
// vi == {1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,...}
```

---

Otherwise, the answer in the linked question isn't entirely accurate since a range may not have the same iterator and sentinel types, and the answer requires it. So we can do a little bit better:

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
auto to_vector(R&& r) {
    std::vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> v;

    // if we can get a size, reserve that much
    if constexpr (requires { std::ranges::size(r); }) {
        v.reserve(std::ranges::size(r));
    }

    // push all the elements
    for (auto&& e : r) {
        v.push_back(static_cast<decltype(e)&&>(e));
    }

    return v;
}
```

A shorter version of the above, which doesn't necessarily reserve up front in all the same places, addresses the mixed-sentinel-type issue by using `views::common`:

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
auto to_vector(R&& r) {
    auto r_common = r | std::views::common;
    return std::vector(r_common.begin(), r_common.end());
}
```

The canonical example of missed reserve here would be invoking `to_vector()` with a `std::list<T>` - which has an O(1) `size()` available, which could be used to reserve, but we lose that once we go into the iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but do you happen to know why the range-v3 to and to_vector functions were dropped from the c++20 spec?

Comment: @Foxie They weren't dropped - they were never in.

Comment: Why were they never in though? It seems like a good thing to be able to do, going from a view back to a concrete container.

Comment: @Foxie It is a good thing. But Ranges is already _massive_. There's a lot of good things that aren't in.

Comment: @Foxie C++23 has added `std::ranges::to`, so you can simply use `yourVectorView | std::ranges::to<std::vector>()`; the template parameter of `std::vector` sometimes can be omitted because of automatic deduction.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry)'s answer and creating an adapter:

```cpp
/**
 * \brief Creates a to_vector_closure for operator()
 */
struct to_vector_adapter
{
    struct closure
    {
        /**
         * \brief Gets a vector of a given range.
         * \tparam R type of range that gets converted to a vector.
         * \param r range that gets converted to a vector.
         * \return vector from the given range.
         */
        template<std::ranges::range R>
        constexpr auto operator()(R&& r) const
        {
            auto r_common = r | std::views::common;
            std::vector<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>> v;

            // if we can get a size, reserve that much
            if constexpr (requires { std::ranges::size(r); }) {
                v.reserve(std::ranges::size(r));
            }

            v.insert(v.begin(), r_common.begin(), r_common.end());

            return v;
        }
    };

    /**
     * \brief Gets a closure to convert the range to a vector.
     * \return A to_vector_closure that will convert the range to a vector.
     */
    constexpr auto operator()() const -> closure
    {
        return closure{};
    }


    template<std::ranges::range R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R&& r)
    {
        return closure{}(r);
    }
};

inline to_vector_adapter to_vector;

/**
 * \brief A range pipe that results in a vector.
 * \tparam R type of range that gets converted to a vector.
 * \param r range that gets converted to a vector.
 * \param a used to create the vector.
 * \return a vector from the given range.
 */
template<std::ranges::range R>
constexpr auto operator|(R&& r, aplasp::planning::to_vector_adapter::closure const& a)
{
    return a(std::forward<R>(r));
}
```

With this you can do something like (where `numbers` is a range of `int`):

```cpp
std::vector foo
{
    numbers
    | std::views::filter([](int n){ return n % 2 == 0; })
    | std::views::transform([](int n){ return n * 2; })
    | to_vector();
};
```

or

```cpp
std::vector foo
{
    to_vector(
        numbers
        | std::views::filter([](int n){ return n % 2 == 0; })
        | std::views::transform([](int n){ return n * 2; }))
};
```