# How to filter and transform cpp vector to another type of vector?

Tags: c++, c++20, stdvector, stl-algorithm, std-ranges

I have a class called InfoBlob and two enums called Action and Emotion. My function is supposed to take in a `vector<InfoBlobs>` blobs, and return a `vector<Action> actions`, corresponding to certain attributes of the blob. However, I have to perform this conversion only in the range of 'first HAPPY blob to the last SAD blob'. Further, within that range, it can only convert blobs that are either HAPPY or SAD.
I have 2 questions:

1. How do I apply this to only the range of 'first HAPPY blob to last SAD blob'
2. How do I transform the vector of InfoBlobs to the vector of actions given the filter condition 'The blobs must be either HAPPY or SAD'.

Right now I am trying to filter it and then transform but I get the error

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<ex4::Action>’ and ‘std::ranges::transform_view<std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<ex4::InfoBlob> >, task03(std::vector<ex4::InfoBlob>)::<lambda(ex4::InfoBlob)> >, task03(std::vector<ex4::InfoBlob>)::<lambda(ex4::InfoBlob)> >’)
   35 |     });
```

This is the class:

```
enum class Emotion : char {
  HAPPY, SAD, PERPLEXED, STRESSED
};

enum class Action : char {
  RUN, LAUGH, WORRY, WEEP, PLAN, PLOT, READ
};


class InfoBlob {
public:
  InfoBlob(int entropy, float spin, Emotion emotion) noexcept
    : entropy{entropy},
      spin{spin},
      emotion{emotion}
      { }

  int getEntropy()     const noexcept { return entropy; }
  float getSpin()      const noexcept { return spin; }
  Emotion getEmotion() const noexcept { return emotion; }

  
  operator==(const InfoBlob& other) const noexcept {
    return entropy == other.entropy
      && spin == other.spin
      && emotion == other.emotion;
  }
```

This is my code:

```
#include "task03.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

using namespace ex4;



std::vector<ex4::Action> task03(std::vector<InfoBlob> blobs){
    
    std::vector<ex4::Action> actions;

    actions = blobs 
    | std::ranges::views::filter([](ex4::InfoBlob blob){
        return blob.getEmotion() == ex4::Emotion::HAPPY || blob.getEmotion() == ex4::Emotion::SAD;
    })
    | std::ranges::views::transform([](ex4::InfoBlob blob){
                        if(blob.getSpin() > blob.getEntropy())
                            return ex4::Action::PLOT;
                        else 
                            return ex4::Action::RUN;
    });

    
return actions;
}
```

Comment: @JeJo Not really working as required: You forgot to take into account that the elements to consider end with the last `SAD` and furthermore that there must be a sad (at least as as I read the requirements) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/axxGvhfPs

Comment: @callum Are you forced to use ranges? Looks like you're having trouble with the "fancy stuff", so it might be better to go with the basics: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zxs63zzxG

Comment: @JeJo, your solution worked, there was a requirement missing but I added that in using a reverse iterator to check for the last sad blob.

Comment: @fabian Unfortunately, I was not allowed to use loops so had to go with ranges.

Comment: If it's only loops you're not allowed to use, `std::for_each` is an option that moves the loop to the standard library just the way the ranges approach moves the loop logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I apply this to only the range of 'first HAPPY blob to last SAD blob'

You want [`drop_while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/drop_while_view). To remove elements past the last `SAD` blob, you can do a `reverse`, then a `drop_while`, then another `reverse`.

> How do I transform the vector of InfoBlobs to the vector of actions given the filter condition 'The blobs must be either HAPPY or SAD'

You've figured out the filter part, so what remains is to create a new vector from a view. See [c++20 ranges view to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63115900/3529323) for a general answer to this problem, but in this case I believe you can just use the iterator pair constructor (you don't know the size in advance, so no missed `reserve` opportunities, and you shouldn't need a `common_view`, since the views used model `common_range` when their underlying views do). C++23 [`std::ranges::to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/to) should make this nicer.

Working code:

```
template<typename Pred>
constexpr auto drop_while_end(Pred &&pred) {
    using namespace std::views;
    return reverse | drop_while(std::forward<Pred>(pred)) | reverse;
}

std::vector<Action> task03(std::vector<InfoBlob> const &blobs) {
    constexpr auto notHappy = [](InfoBlob const &blob) { return blob.getEmotion() != Emotion::HAPPY; };
    constexpr auto notSad = [](InfoBlob const &blob) { return blob.getEmotion() != Emotion::SAD; };
    constexpr auto happyOrSad = [](InfoBlob const &blob) {
        return blob.getEmotion() == Emotion::HAPPY || blob.getEmotion() == Emotion::SAD;
    };
    constexpr auto blobToAction = [](InfoBlob const &blob) {
        return blob.getSpin() > blob.getEntropy() ? Action::PLOT : Action::RUN;
    };

    using namespace std::views;
    auto actions = blobs
                   | drop_while(notHappy)
                   | drop_while_end(notSad)
                   | filter(happyOrSad)
                   | transform(blobToAction);
    return {actions.begin(), actions.end()};
}
```