# Is one-line initialization of a <set> possible with C++20 <ranges>?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I would like to know if with `<ranges>` in C++20 it is finally possible to select from a sequence and initialize a `set` in one line, as is possible in C# with `IEnumerable`. This would probably require converting a `<ranges>` object to a `std::initializer_list`.

C#:

```
int[] sequence = new int[] { 0,1,2,3,4 };
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(sequence.Where((int i) => i % 2 == 0));
```

C++:

```
std::vector<int> sequence { 0,1,2,3,4 };
auto matcher = sequence | std::ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return !(i % 2); });
std::set<int> myset(matcher.begin(), matcher.end());
```

I want to do something like:

```
std::vector<int> sequence { 0,1,2,3,4 };
std::set<int> myset { sequence | std::ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return !(i % 2); }) };
```

Comment: You can just write your own extention [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971856)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is not possible for now, but in near future, we can get [ranges::to](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1206r1.pdf) which will have such functionality.