# Is there any way to preserve white-space indentation across new lines? (using fmtlib)

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I'm using fmtlib to help format some automatically generated code. My problem comes when composing multi-line indented string, such as:

```cpp
auto str = fmt::format(
  "{header}\n"
  "  {body}\n"
  "{footer}",
  fmt::var("header", single_line_str()),
  fmt::var("body", multi_line_str()),
  fmt::var("footer", single_line_str()) 
);
```

Now, suppose the header was `"begin"`, the footer was `"end"`, and the multi-line body was:

```
The quick brown\n
fox jumped over\n
the lazy dog
```

The result would be something like this:

```
begin
  The quick brown
fox jumped over
the lazy dog
end
```

When then desired output should be something like this instead:

```
begin
  The quick brown
  fox jumped over
  the lazy dog
end
```

So, my question is, **is there any way to preserve the indentation specified in the original format string across multi-line string literals**?

One approach I tried was to let each of the literal strings handle its own indentation. For example, a format string of:

```cpp
auto str = fmt::format(
  "{header}\n"
  "{body}\n"
  "{footer}",
  fmt::var("header", single_line_str()),
  fmt::var("body", multi_line_str()),
  fmt::var("footer", single_line_str()) 
);
```

With the body being:

```
  The quick brown
  fox jumps over
  the lazy dog
```

This yields the correct results, but if the body string ends up being anything more complex (i.e. if its nested multiply internally), then this does not work, as the formatting is no longer relative, it's absolute.

Comment: You'd need to do it yourself.  `{fmt}` doesn't have this specific use-case built in.

Comment: I'm not sure about `fmt`, but it should not be hard to add indents with a funciton.

Comment: fwiw for the function there is no difference from your string than `"{header}\n  {body}\n{footer}"`

Comment: Implementation provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of allocating a huge `vector` to store the split `string`s, you can simply use `fmt::join`

```
#include <ranges>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

auto my_format(std::string_view header, 
               std::string_view body,
               std::string_view footer,
               int indent_level = 1)
{
  std::string indent(indent_level * 2, ' ');
  return fmt::format(
    "{}\n"
    "{}{}\n"
    "{}",
    header, 
    indent,
    fmt::join(
      body | std::views::split('\n')
           | std::views::transform([](auto r) { return std::string_view(r); }),
      "\n" + indent),  
    footer);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M7rf7jqWG)

Comment: interesting solution, thank you. I have never used fmt/ranges, but I should!

Comment: ok on second thought, this only works for C++23, which I feel is currently a limitation. The problem is constructing the std::string_view from the range.

Comment: Then in C++20 you can `return std::string_view(r.begin(), r.end());`

Comment: fair enough, that works!

Answer (score 1):

After the advice given I have written my own implementation, as follows:

```
auto join_strings(const auto& container, const std::string& delim) -> std::string
{
  return std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), std::string(), 
  [delim](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) -> std::string { 
    return a + (a.length() > 0 ? delim : "") + b; 
  });
}

static
auto indent(std::string_view multi_line_str, unsigned indent_level) -> std::string
{
  using namespace std::literals;
  auto indented_strs = multi_line_str
    | views::split("\n"sv)
    | views::transform([&](auto&& rng){
      std::string line(&*rng.begin(), ranges::distance(rng));
      line.insert(0, 2 * indent_level, ' ');
      return line;
    })
    | utility::to<std::vector<std::string>>();
  return utility::join_strings(indented_strs, "\n");
}
```

where the `utility::to<>()` function uses the implementation found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60971856/21135657